# Azure DevOps agent pool used by my pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have pipeline defined in YAML file where the following section exists

```
jobs:
  - displayName: Name X
    pool: pool1
```

I see `Agent name: 'agent1'` in the logs of the runs (`agent1` is a part of `pool1`).
So far all looks good. However, when I run below command (11764 is one of builds of my pipeline) I receive:

```
$ az pipelines runs show --org=${ORG} --project="${PROJECT}" --id 11764 | jq .queue
{
  "id": 9,
  "name": "Azure Pipelines",
  "pool": {
    "id": 9,
    "isHosted": true,
    "name": "Azure Pipelines"
  },
  "url": null
}
```

The question is. Should I defined pool in a different way or on another level? Or maybe there is something I'm not taking to consideration?

Comment: what is `pool1`? is MS pool or private pool?

Comment: The job definition doesn't look right, in your pipeline yaml; shouldn't it start with `-job: NameX` ?

Comment: `pool1` is a private pool

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, `az pipelines runs show` command  will get the Agent Pool information defined on the YAML Pipeline UI(navigate to  **Triggers -> YAML** ) but not the Agent Pool information defined in YAML.

[image]

Therefore, although the definition in your YAML is correct, the response of `az pipelines runs show` command is still Microsoft-Hosted agent Pool.

To alleviate this issue, you can change the agent pool to pool1 in YAML Pipline UI.

[image]